# PySpark reading from JSON file with nested struct fields and dynamic keys

Tags: json, pyspark

I need to process following JSON data:
https://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/api/v1/GG_DEBT_GDP

The data should be transformed to a high table with year, country and value columns. The solution should be dynamic and react to data from incoming new periods.

How can this be achieved ? Are there any useful built-in functions to deal with such a file or loops should be used ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the following ways.

Using PySpark:

```py
import requests
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

response = requests.get("https://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/api/v1/GG_DEBT_GDP")
json_data = response.json()["values"]["GG_DEBT_GDP"]

data_list = [{"year": year, "country": country, "value": value}
             for country, values in json_data.items()
             for year, value in values.items()]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data_list, schema="year STRING, country STRING, value STRING")
df.show()
```

Using Pandas + PySpark:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

json_data = pd.read_json("https://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/api/v1/GG_DEBT_GDP")["values"][0]
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data)
      .reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "year"})
      .melt(id_vars="year", var_name="country", value_name="value"))

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
spark_df.show()
```

Both give the following output:

```
+----+-------+---------------+
|year|country|          value|
+----+-------+---------------+
|1950|    USA|83.126037377225|
|1951|    USA|72.955032400931|
|1952|    USA| 72.52549154977|
|1953|    USA|71.753218636523|
|1954|    USA|73.568066469359|
|1955|    USA|68.498633447214|
|1956|    USA|64.726033476873|
|1957|    USA|62.329546033921|
|1958|    USA|64.927332482752|
|1959|    USA|62.335885122406|
|1960|    USA| 60.83294667213|
|1961|    USA|61.393351025592|
|1962|    USA|59.371677777831|
|1963|    USA|57.954915607618|
|1964|    USA|55.988828640074|
|1965|    USA|53.060492322606|
|1966|    USA| 50.14458097802|
|1967|    USA|50.395848934109|
|1968|    USA|48.736870113876|
|1969|    USA|45.939659073617|
+----+-------+---------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```